# Is there an SQL database that can rollback in time?

Tags: database, database-design, temporal-database

I am looking for an SQL database of some type that is entirely based around the concept of time, just like those that are geo-centric, relationship-centric, etc.

My main wish is that I can make changes to the database as I go along, and then at any point run a query that essentially says, show me how the database looked at this date and time. I would prefer the SQL database have this functionality built in, instead of having to re-implement it using a log table and recording each and every transaction.

Am I hoping for a pipe dream?

Thanks!

EDIT: After some further research, it seems that a "[temporal database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database)" might be what I'm looking for. So any information on using one of those, if there are any good open-source ones available, etc., would be very helpful!

Comment: I believe for my purposes it would be fine to assume that the structure of the database would remain unchanged. The data, however, would change.

Comment: Your question, then, confuses the issue.  You need to define your database schema to handle the fact that your data is only valid for certain periods of time by inserting records specifying those time periods.  The way the question is written has made some of the folks below wonder if you wish to do queries on metadata (what did the database look like before I ran this DELETE statement?).  This solution is something you need to get around by good schema design, not having a special journal or using some historical recovery tool.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. Any links you can provide that might point me in the right direction or provide some information about the good schema design to use in this instance would be helpful.

Comment: Can do.  What kind of knowledge do you have of relational databases?  If I know where your'e at knowledged/experience-wise, it'll make it easier to recommend something.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to read some introductory stuff on relational database design.  I'd look up stuff on (in this order) database design, ERD (to give you a conceptual way of looking at the problem), good descriptions on different types of table keys.  Then I'd try to map out the schema you'd need on paper, and then perhaps using Dia or Visio's ERD/Database design objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle has [Flashback](http://www.oracle.com/technology/deploy/availability/htdocs/Flashback_Overview.htm).  Closest I can think of on [SQL Server requires snapshots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175876.aspx), without resorting to restoring from transaction logs (requires full recovery model).

Comment: I'm looking for something that treats this more like a "feature", not a recovery tool.

After reading about temporal DB's, that seems to be the ticket. You can basically query the database and say "as of right now, what do you think about X", but you can also say "as of Y time, what did you think about X?", even if the values would (in a typical DB) have been overwritten by then.

Comment: @Riley Dutton: Oracle's Flashback is the closest I know of then.  What you ask for is typically transaction log domain...

Comment: That's exactly how Oracle's flashback works. 
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
AS OF TIMESTAMP '2010-01-01' (or a similar syntax)

You can even set the whole transaction to a point in the past, and then all queries will return values from back then.

To go a really long way back, you'll need Oracle 11g and it's "Flashback Archive" which is quite costly though.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information. I think Oracle is probably a non-starter, since it costs money, but maybe reading about it will give me some good ideas.

Comment: @Riley Dutton: Take a look over at otn.oracle.com. You can get the database for free for development purposes, not sure about Flashback. Unless they've changed their policies over the past few years, you aren't time limited on the development usage, just once it goes into production, you need to properly license it.

Comment: @RileyDutton, @ManiacZX, @a_horse_with_no_name : Oracle's Total Recall (aka Flashback Archive) option - which is the temporal database implementation - is a chargeable extra on the Enterprise Edition, so it *is* expensive.  However, the markup isn't as gouging as some of Oracle's other chargeable extras and the feature does work really neatly.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [TimeDB](http://www.timeconsult.com/TemporalData/TemporalDBMS.html).

Note, though, that you can do the exact same thing yourself by implementing a ValidTimeBegin and ValidTimeEnd columns in your tables and populating them accordingly.  The tool simply takes its special SQL statements and converts them to SQL92-compliant statements.

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for software historian. These are databases where all data is organised temporally, really their core function. Once of the uses of the software historian, is to enable a playback function, where time series data can be played back in the order it was entered,  which is often critical in those industries that require it, like real time applications in finance, gas, oil and electric utilities.

Some of the companies that offer software historians, are

[Wonderware](http://global.wonderware.com/EN/Pages/WonderwareDataHistorian.aspx)
[FactoryTalk](http://www.rockwellautomation.com/rockwellsoftware/data/historian/)
[OSI PI](http://www.osisoft.com/software-support/what-is-pi/what_is_pi_.aspx)

Comment: I worked with PI Historian (for years).  It is great at capturing history, but it is not really a temoporal database.  A temporal database allows bulk updates of the past such that you have two copies of the past, one prior to the update and one after the update.  As such, you can select the current "truth" or the "truth as it was known on X date".  PI only stores (in a very compressed manner) one truth value for the past, so it is not actually a temporal database, it is more of a time series database.